# Why is enabling 8 bit control sequences not recommended?

Tags: rxvt

`./configure --help`: **--enable-8bitctrls** enable 8 bit control sequences (not recommended)

As far as I can tell, the only affected code is this part of `src/command.C`:

```c
/*{{{ process non-printing single characters */
void ecb_hot
rxvt_term::process_nonprinting (unicode_t ch)
{
  switch (ch)
    {
//
// skipping non-relevant lines
//
#ifdef EIGHT_BIT_CONTROLS
      // 8-bit controls
      case 0x90:        /* DCS */
        process_dcs_seq ();
        break;
      case 0x9b:        /* CSI */
        process_csi_seq ();
        break;
      case 0x9d:        /* OSC */
        process_osc_seq ();
        break;
#endif
    }
}
/*}}} */
```

So, I suppose the problem is not with rvxt-unicode code itself. What bad things could happen if 8-bit control sequences are enabled?

Comment: bytes with the 8th bit set are used for non-ASCII characters (all charset in locales of most Unix-like systems being supersets of ASCII). So using that would only make sense for people in the US using ASCII-only locales and dealing with American-English only text.

Comment: There are 10s of thousands of characters in Unicode whose UTF-8 encoding contains the 0x9b byte. CSI can also be expressed as the ESC `[` sequence and that's what most applications use. (like in `\e[1m` to turn on bold mode)

Comment: More generally the C1 control character set is mostly obsolete these days with hardly anything still using it.

Comment: See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Fe_Escape_sequences

Comment: Perhaps you will provide a script which counts the "10s of thousands", so that others can compare results.

Comment: @ThomasDickey no need for a script — 0x9B is 0b10011011, and since it starts with 0b10, it can appear as bytes 2, 3, and/or 4 in a 2–4-byte UTF-8 sequence. That gives 2⁵ code points with 2 bytes, ~2¹¹ with 3, and ~2¹⁶ with 4 if my calculations are correct, *i.e.* getting on for 70,000 code points.